# what does "in a way" emphasize?

Tags: phrase-meaning, emphasis

> On  the  way  he  soon  became  lost  in  philosophical  speculations.  "Ghee,"  he  said  to himself, "comes  from  cow's  milk.  Cows  eat  grass,  and  yes,  leaves,  too.  Ah  then, ** in  a  way**,  ghee  comes from  cow's  milk,  and  cow's  milk  comes  from  leaves,  and  so  the  ghee  and  the leaf  are  related!

This paragraph is from a folk tale.The question is :
which sentence does the phrase "in a way" emphasize?
Does it mean "to some extent"?

Comment: Does [this](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+way) help?

Answer (score 2):

*In a way* means "looking at something with one perspective" ( as opposed, perhaps, to another).  And *in a way*  may be used to indicate a partial assessment of something. 
The link Teacher KSHuang provided will help.
There are several possibilities in your example sentence:

> *In a way*, ghee is related to the water the cow drinks.
>
> *In a way*, ghee is related to the grass the cow eats

[Cambridge Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/in-a-way)

[Collins Dictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/in-a-way)